# denied due to lack of policy file permissions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, yahoo, flash-cs4

I can't get my Yahoo! Application Platform to run I keep getting denied access even though their policy file accepts requests from any domain.

```
OK: Policy file accepted: http://social.yahooapis.com/crossdomain.xml
Error: Request for resource at http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/<user id>/profile?oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&lang=en-US&oauth_consumer_key=<key>&oauth_token=<long ass token>&oauth_version=1.0&format=json&oauth_nonce=<blah blah>&oauth_timestamp=1262846353&region=US&oauth_signature=<foo bar> by requestor from http://<my domain>/YOSSimple.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.
```

The url works btw, I editted some stuff out since it has my keys and stuff.

---

Links to the stuff I'm trying to do

```
http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/yos/
http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/yos/examples/simple/YOSSimple.fla
```

YOSSimple properly creates the url actually since if I type it in my browser I'm prompted if I want to download the file that contains information regarding my profile.

But it just wont open it in Flash.

Comment: what's you security sandbox? Try with local trusted as I don't see any issue with crossdomain policy file.

Comment: I'm using CS4 btw. I've already set its publish settings to `Access network only` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post the code that does the request that's failing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that it's not loading the policy file automatically. You should try using
`Security.loadPolicyFile("http://social.yahooapis.com/crossdomain.xml");`

Do you have a webproxy installed with which you can monitor what files exactly are loaded? My favorite is [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) but there are also free FF plugins like [Httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647)

EDIT:
I think I know what's going wrong. It's going wrong the other way around, the swf from yahoo is trying to access your swf, but doesn't have the correct permissions. Would you try

```
Security.allowDomain( 'http://social.yahooapis.com/' );
```

Comment: Already tried manually loading the policy, still didn't work. Will try that webproxy thing in a few.

Comment: The files are being loaded no problems there. [http://social.yahooapis.com/crossdomain.xml, YOSSimple.swf, etc]. It says that it loads the SWF first before the XML tho, would that be the problem?

Comment: No, that's how it should be.
BTW, I edited my answer, I think I know what's going wrong.

Comment: Grrr! :-)
Then I'm out of ideas... If you do find it, could you post the solution? I'm really curious now!

Comment: If I ever do :( but I kinda moved on, I used their PHP SDK instead=..=

Comment: I think that the argument to allowDomain should be just "social.yahooapis.com."  Of course, you could use "*" to check if that's even related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/

use HTTP analyzer to see whats happening?

also check your not missmatching http://www. with http:// because flash treats them as different domains

also are you running the code locally on your machine. It could be your local security settings

Answer (score 0):

A simple WebProxy will fix this:

```
<?php
    // PHP Proxy
    // Loads a XML from any location. Used with Flash/Flex apps to bypass security restrictions
    // usage: proxy.php?url=http://mysite.com/myxml.xml

    $session = curl_init($_GET['url']);                    // Open the Curl session
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);          // Don't return HTTP headers
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   // Do return the contents of the call
    $xml = curl_exec($session);                            // Make the call
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");                  // Set the content type appropriately
    echo $xml;        // Spit out the xml
    curl_close($session); // And close the session
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the web proxy example above to support multiple options as follows:

```
$sOptions = "";

foreach($_GET as $sIndex => $sValue) {
  if ($sIndex == 'url') {
    $url = $sValue;
  } 
  else {
    if (strlen($sIndex) > 0) {
      $sOptions .= "&" . $sIndex;
    }
    if (strlen($sValue) > 0) {
      $sOptions .= "=" . $sValue;
    }
  }
}

$url .= $sOptions;

$session = curl_init($url); // Open the Curl session
```